# AWS DYNAMODB: How to get email notification based on CRUD operations?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

AWS DYNAMODB: How to get email notification based on CRUD operations ?

Answer (score 0):

If reacting to changes in items in your table is what you're looking for, have a look at [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html).

They allow you to hook into previously mentioned changes, and execute custom code upon them. The custom code could be then leveraged to send email when changes occur.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you enable [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) on the tables, then create an [AWS Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) in your programming language of choice that consumes that Stream. If there is only some data you care about, create an [event filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html) in Lambda to only fire the Lambda function when the filter criteria are met. The Lambda function could then be programmed to use something like [Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html) to send the email.